# Ajax in Rails and render

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm learning about ajax, but even the first applications I write it remains inactive. After clicking the link, nothing changes.

**cart_controller.rb**

```
def cart_add_quan
        id_cart = params[:id]
        cart = session[:cart]
        cart.each do |id, quantity|
            if id_cart == id then
                cart[id] += 1
            end
        end
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html {redirect_to cart_path}
            format.js
        end
    end
```

views/cart/**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Your cart:</h1>
<td><%= link_to 'Continue shopping', product_user_index_path %></td>
<% if @cart.empty? %>
    <p>Your cart is empty</p>
<% else %>
<div id="carts">
    <%= render 'carts' %>
    <br>
        <h2><%= link_to 'Check out', check_out_index_path %></h2>
    <br>
    <td><%= link_to 'Empty your cart', cart_clear_path %></td>
</div>
<% end %>
```

views/cart/**_carts.html.erb**

```
<br>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product name</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>SubPrice</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <br>
            <% @cart.each do |id, quantity| %>
            <% product = Product.find_by_id(id) %>

            <tr>
                <td><%= link_to product.name, product %></td>
                <td><%= image_tag(product.image.thumb('45x45#').url, class: "SlideItMoo_element") if product.image_stored? %></td>
                <td><%= product.description.html_safe %></td>
                <td><%= sub_price(product, quantity) %></td>
                <td>
**#link to *cart_quan_path***
                    <%= link_to "+", cart_add_quan_path(id), remote: true %> 
                    <%= quantity %>
                    <%= link_to "-", cart_sub_quan_path(id) %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'remove', cart_remove_product_path(id) %></td>
            </tr>
            <% end %>
        </tbody>    
    </table>
<h3 id ="total">Totald: <%= totalCart(@cart) %></h3>
```

views/cart/**cart_add_quan.js.erb**

```
$('#carts').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("carts")) %>');
console.log("hihi");
```

Comment: on which page you are clicking the link to load response from cart_add_quan...is it the index.html.erb page ?

Comment: @Milind yes, it's index.html.erb, but the link cart_add_quan in _carts.html.erb

Comment: the issue is like your link where you are clicking is inside the same partial which you want to render after clicking the partial.

Comment: @AdnanDevops 
that means I have to recalculate the value each div tag? eg $ ('# total'). html (" Totald: <% = totalCart (cart)%> '); but still does not change the value. Could you please let me know how to recalculate at each div tag? Thanks.

Comment: is cart_add_quan.js.erb working .verify putting an alert("working ").Also if this js.erb is working can you help me to show whether _carts..html.erb is working by removing <%= render 'carts' %> and trying it.

Comment: Is your `console.log("hihi");` being executed when you click an add button? Also, check your server log when you click an add button, see if it is listing any errors with getting the page.

Comment: I think it may be the `_carts.html.erb` looks for an `@cart` which isn't set by your `cart_add_quan` action. You'll need to add an `@cart` variable that works the same as your `index` `@cart` variable.

Comment: I've recalculated each Div tag, it works fine but I do not think that's a good way. :(
`$('#total').html("Total: <%= @total %>");
$('#sub_price<%= @product.id %>').html("<%= @sub_total %>");
$('#quantity<%= @product.id %>').html("<%=  @cart[@product.id.to_s] %>");
console.log("hihi");`